# Does hdparm have an option to test the write speed?

Tags: centos, filesystems, hard-disk, hardware, hdparm

```
hdparm -t [device]
```

tells me the read speed.  Is there a way to show the write speed? When I `man hdarm | grep write` I get flags `-F`, `-n`, `-r` and `-W`, all which do not provide the desired result I am looking for.

Then is there a way to show read and write speeds with one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*hdparm* does not have the ability to find the write speed. According to the information under [how to test the read and write speeds of a hard disk in linux](https://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-test-the-read-and-write-speeds-of-a-hard-disk-in-linux/#:%7E:text=hdparm%20does%20not%20have%20the%20ability%20to%20find,disk%20which%20can%20then%20be%20measured%20for%20speed.), you can time a call to *dd*, or use the tools *Bonnie++* and *piozone*.

Answer (score 1):

Any idea why hdparm did not implement a write test ?

I use f3probe's f3write to report speed on existing filesystem (not device)

gnome-disk-utility also work but it require UI, see example at:

https://mastodon.social/@rzr/104705031512211575#sdcard

Note numbers are not same.